# git- Pull option missing in source control xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I'm working with git, I have cloned a project from main branch, then I made some changes in one of the files, and I got a commit option in source control menu to commit the code.

*After successful commit when I want to pull the code from remote server I did not find any option "Pull".*

Please check this attached screenshot.

[image]

What did I miss in the setup? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the git repo url is not correct. Please check your git url.

Comment: @VijayMasiwal thanks,my git repository is correct only.

Comment: Are you able to see your working copies under source control?

Comment: @VijayMasiwal yes, i can see my working copies

Comment: Have you tried with terminal using command `git pull`

Comment: @VijayMasiwal and push option also disabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79318/discussion-between-mutablegopi-and-vijay-masiwal).

Comment: @vijayMasiwal no, because i need to pull the code from particular branch.